# 3 errors: error: 'Entry' was not declared in this scope. error: template argument 1 is invalid. error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token

Tags: c++, templates, vector, compiler-errors, declaration

Noob here, sorry for the error filled title.

I'm trying to compile this segment of code from Bjarne Stroustrup's 'The C++ Programming Language' but CodeBlocks keeps throwing me this error.

The code is about range checking an array held in a vector function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int i = 1000;

template<class T> class Vec : public vector<T>
{
public:
    Vec() : vector<T>() { }

    T& operator[] (int i) {return vector<T>::at(i); }
    const T& operator[] (int i) const {return vector<T>::at(i); }
    //The at() operation is a vector subscript operation 
    //that throws an exception of type out_of_range
    //if its argument is out of the vector's range.
};

Vec<Entry> phone_book(1000); //this line is giving me trouble

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

It's giving me these errors:

- error: 'Entry' was not declared in this scope.
- error: template argument 1 is invalid.
- error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token.

What do I have to change? How do I declare Vec Entry ?

Comment: You have not declared Entry. Entry is a type you pass on to the Vec template class. It may be a struct or a class, but it hasn't been defined anywhere in your code so you can't use it.

Comment: `Entry` seems to be a few pages before this sample.

Comment: Also there's no Vec<T> constructor that takes an integer.

Comment: If using C++11, TC++PL 4th edition has the line `using vector<T>::vector;` to inherit the constructors as well.

Comment: @BernardoPliego-Garcia, In the public section of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I doubt that you directly copied this piece of code from Bjarne. However, the problem is just what the error says: `Entry` is not declared. 
If you simply want to play around with the example, you can try for example

```
Vec<int>
```

instead. However, there is another small problem (and this is the one that makes me believe you changed Bjarnes code): Your class `Vec` has no constructor that takes an `int`, thus

```
Vec<int> phone_book(1000);
```

cannot work. Just supply this constructor:

```
Vec(int size) : vector<T>(size) {}
```

and it should work.